# Pseudo-element :after is adding before instead

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, pseudo-element

I applied the pseudo-element :after to the chapter-heading class, but for some reason it appears on top of the row instead of underneath it (I'm trying to create an underline).

HTML:

```
                <div class="row chapter-heading">
                    <button class="btn btn-lesson-toc" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tocModal">
                    <i class="material-icons icon-align">list</i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                        <h5>${card.title}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-9 text-left">
                        <div class="lesson-card" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cardDetailModal">
                            <h6>${card.heading}</h6>
                            <p>${card.shortInfo}</p>
                            <img src="${card.cartoonUrl}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.chapter-heading:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: $scoops-grey-400;
  // border: 1px solid $scoops-grey-400;
  left: 35%;
}
```

Comment: `:after` is not a pseudo-element. Use `::after` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:after` and `:before` have to include `content` property.

```
.chapter-heading:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: $scoops-grey-400;
  left: 35%;
}
```

Make sure `.chapter-heading` class have `position: relative`.

You should add `top: 100%` or `bottom: 0` for `.chapter-heading:after` to make a underline.

Comment: Can you also explain why .chapter-heading has to be position:relative and :after position:absolute? Also, I removed content: ""; and it still works.

Comment: Please read more about position to understand at https://webdevdoor.com/html-css/css-position-child-div-parent

Answer (score 1):

```
.chapter-heading {
  position: relative;
}

.chapter-heading:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  left: 35%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b41maatw/)